# Is it safe to add to a collection (mutable NSArray/NSDictionary) inside enumerateObjectWithBlock?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks, foundation

Is this code safe to execute? That is, is it safe to add to a NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary concurrently?

```
- (NSArray *)batchProcess:(NSArray *)inputList {
    NSMutableArray *outputList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:inputList.count];

    [inputList enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent 
               usingBlock:^(id thing, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
        id processedThing = [self doProcessingOn:thing];

        [outputList addObject:processedThing];
    }];

    return outputList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it safe to add to a NSMutableArray or NSMutableDictionary concurrently?

Unless you provide your own synchronization mechanism which guarantees only one thread uses it at any given time, **It is NOT safe**. If you use it in a way that is not thread safe, you should expect undefined behavior.